# Partial screenshot of iOS home screen - allowed or not?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm getting ready to submit the first version of my app and I have a question about one potential review issue.  I've read the App Store Review Guidelines but it doesn't quite cover this.

I don't need to tell you much about my app, apart from the fact that one main selling point is that it does its main function (fetches some data & displays it) straight away when the app starts up.  It's a "one-touch" solution, if you like.  But to get to that stage, the user will need to do a bit of setup of exactly which information they want to see when it starts up etc.

So, in order to demonstrate what they'll end up with after setup, I wanted to show a few introductory screens on first startup, with the final one having a "...and here's one we prepared earlier" sort of button which would lead to a demo of the finished product.  This button will be fairly large and I want it to show a crop of the phone's home screen with my app's icon, so they can simulate starting the app and then seeing their data straight away.  I hope that makes sense.

I'm wondering whether it will be ok to include in the snapshot crop some partial icons of surrounding apps on the home screen.  Here's an example mockup (https://www.dropbox.com/s/76gpxvski642g6j/Photo%203-12-2013%2012%2024%2034%20am.png).  If it's going to be a problem having these partial shots of stock icons, that's fine, I can just create some dummy app icons myself to surround my real one.  But I'd rather have it like it is below.  Can anyone tell me if I'm worried about nothing or if they actually are likely to not like this for some reason?  Any thoughts welcome.
cheers
Ian

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's app review policies and not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app store selection process can feel like black magic sometimes, so your concerns are not entirely misplaced. However, they do give feedback and you can request clarifications - its not an all-or-nothing affair. They want good apps in their store, and they will work with you (to some, varying, degree) to achieve that on these sorts of packaging details.

If I were you, I would submit the image that you think works best. If it is rejected, it will include a rejection code, which you can lookup and potentially ask followup questions. It sounds like you already have a backup plan so you should be fine. Good luck!

**tl;dr: Upload your ideal image to the app store, handle rejection if needed.**

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can include any image you'd like - just make sure the resolution is correct.